# Apexcharts select or unselect dataPoint with legend

Tags: reactjs, charts, apexcharts

I have problem to select bar dataPoint when I click on legend.

When I click "Operational", the green bar disappears.
[image]

Instead I want to highlight "Operational" above the others (similar to onItemHover but permanent. And the other captions will be dimmed:
[image]

I can do it?
Now, for me it is impossible.

I have similar behaviour than https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiOTFhYWNjNDgtZTk1YS00OWM1LTgyOWQtNTYxMWJlZjJhYWM3IiwidCI6ImU3MzRkOTVlLTM3MDUtNDFjMC1iNTZkLWMzZTI2OWU5YWJlNCIsImMiOjl9

Examples:

Pass 1:
I want to highlight "Operational":
When I click in legend "Operational" I want to select the bar "GREEN".

Pass 2:
I want to highlight "Operational" and "Outage":
If I click in "Operational" and "Outage" I want to select the bars "GREEN" and "RED".

Pass 3:
Now, if I click another time in "Operational" the bars selected will be "RED" ("Outage").

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found the solution to this problem? I am also facing a similar problem.

Comment: I used native CSS to resolve this problem. https://css-tricks.com/making-charts-with-css/